# Angular 4 / Laravel .subscribe() will not executed

Tags: javascript, laravel, angular

```
    login(){
    console.log("Test1");
    this.authService.login(this.userForm.value)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          console.log("Test2");
          console.log(response);
          if(response === true){
            this.router.navigate(['/admin']);
          }else {
            this.status = "error";
            this.message = "Username or password is incorrect";
          }
        },
        error => {
          console.log(<any>error);
          this.status = "error";
          this.message = error ['message'];
        }
      );
  }
```

Test1 will shown in the console, but Test2 will not. It seems that the subscribe function is never executed.

The function `login()` will be called by the submit button of my Angular Form. 
If I submit my form, there comes an error. Look below at the line with .catch... The error calls "Server Error"

```
    login(user: Object): Observable<any>{
      return this.http.post('CENSORED LINK TO API', user)
        .map((response: Response) => {
          let token = response.json().token;
          console.log("Response token: " + token);

          if(token){
            this.token = token;
            localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(this.token));
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        })
        .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || { message: "Server Error"}));
  }
```

[here is a picture from the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CS56.png)

Comment: If you say you get an error, it helps adding details about the error to your question.

Comment: The Error is "Server Error" from .catch... see in last line of the second Code. I will edit it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have finallay an answer.

For others with the same Problem, put this lines into the index.php of your laravel api. Be sure that you paste this above the line with

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

Do not forget to edit the `$allowedOrigins` to be sure that your POST request has access to the url of the laravel api.

```
    $allowedOrigins = array(
    '(http(s)://)?angular-elearning-user(\.)?c9users\.io',
    '(http(s)://)?angular-elearning-user(\.)?c9users\.io(\:)8081',
    '(http(s)://)?angular-elearning-user(\.)?c9users\.io(\:)8082',
    'https://localhost:8081',
    'https://localhost:8082'
);

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] != ''){
    foreach ($allowedOrigins as $allowedOrigins){
        if(preg_match('#' . $allowedOrigins . '#', $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])){
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
            header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

and put this into Cors.php

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Content-Type, x-xsrf-token');
}
```

Thats it.

If you have still errors, then try your form POST request with Insomnia or Postman for Google Chrome.